# Showcase of beautiful section styles combinations

Tags: sectioning, typography, examples, big-list

Working with all kinds books, I often need inspiration for *a set of* sectioning styles that are coherent, logical and aesthetically appealing. Well-known examples include [Edward Tufte](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex?lang=en) and the style used in Robert Bringhurst's [The Elements of Typographic Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792128).

I would kindly like to ask you to show your examples—all the better if the example includes LaTeX source. If you refer to a specific author or publication, it would be useful to include an image.

The mentioned examples are typically limited to chapter title, section and subsection. At times, I need a set of styles with more depth—chapter title, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph, etc. So sets with more depth are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether the examples you give are examples of what you want or examples of what you don't want. That is, first you say they are examples of what you are looking for. But then you say you need `a set of styles with more depth`. If this means more depth than Tufte/Bringhurst, then presumably neither was an example, well-known or otherwise, of `a set of sectioning styles...` in the first place. If it doesn't mean that, then what does it mean?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends

Comment: @John That is one of my favorite wikis.

Comment: I'm under the impression that these types of non-questions aren't as welcome here now  as they were a few years ago.

Answer (score 4):

See the `memoir` manual (try `texdoc memoir` or `texdoc memman`) sections 6.5 and 6.6 which show a variety of chapter and lower level headings in a variety of styles together with the code to produce them (but for the code of some of the chapterstyles you will have to look in the the actual `memoir` class file). Note that the several chapter styles are integral to the `memoir` class.

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely don't claim it to be "beautiful", but would like by posting my own sectioning style to encourage other answers.

This is my attempt at a (very) compact style for un-numbered sections:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Unnumbered titles.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen}

% Playing with the fonts
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalfont\itshape}

% Playing with the spacing
\RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-.35\baselineskip, afterskip=.15\baselineskip]{section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[afterskip=-.5\baselineskip]{paragraph, subparagraph}
\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}

% Color from https://bedienhaptik.de/latex-template/
\definecolor[named]{myColorMainA}{RGB}{0,26,153}

% Coloring the titles
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{myColorMainA}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{myColorMainA}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\color{myColorMainA}}
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\color{myColorMainA}}
\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\color{myColorMainA}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Level 1}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    \subsection{Level 2}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    \subsubsection{Level 3}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    \paragraph{Level 4}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    \subparagraph{Level 5}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

[image]